# How to retain audio from Websocket call to Bluemix speech2text service?

Tags: audio, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text

We have a iOS native app client making calls to a Bluemix speech2text service using Websockets in Direct interaction mode, which works great for us (very fast, very low latency).  But we do need to retain a copy of the audio stream.  Most audio clips are short (< 60 seconds).  Is there an easy way to do that?

We can certainly have the client buffer the audio clip and upload it somewhere when convenient.  This may increase memory footprint, particularly for longer clips.  And impact app performance, if not done carefully.

Alternatively, we could switch to using HTTP interface and relay via a proxy, which could then keep a copy for us.  The concern here (other that re-writing an app that works perfectly fine for us) is that this may increase latency due to extra hops in the main call thread.

Any insights would be appreciated.

-rg

Comment: Use a proxy and specify the proxy URL in the SDK. You just need to make sure the proxy uses a multi thread language like Java because you will be doing a lot of I/O

Comment: I see two main options: 1) use a websocket proxy and capture the audio there before pushing it to Watson STT. 2) do a POST with transfer encoding chunked to POST the audio to your storage solution as a stream so you do not run into memory issues. This would be done in a background thread and should be very cheap.

Comment: I was secretly hoping there might be a way to get the last audio clip from  Watson STT somehow, alas does not sounds like it.  Short of that, both proxy suggestions sound legit--we'll give them a try.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

After some additional research we settled on using Amazon S3 TransferUtility Mobile SDK for iOS.  It encapsulates data chunking and multi-threading within a single object, and even completes transfer in the background after iOS suspends the app.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transferutility.html

The main advantages we see:

- no impact on existing code--simply add a call to initiate a transfer
- no need to implement and maintain a proxy server, which reduces complexity

Bluemix provides cloud object storage similar to S3 but we were unable to find an iOS SDK that supports anything other than a synchronous, single-threaded solution right out of the box (we were initially psyched to see 'Swift' support, but that has proven to be just a coincidental use of terms).

Answer (score 0):

My two cents....

I would switch to the HTTP interface, if you make things tougher for your users, then they won't use your app and will figure out a better way to do things.  You shouldn't have to rewrite the app - just the communications, and then have some sort of server side application that will "cache" those audio streams.

Another approach would be to leave your application as is, and just add a step to send the audio file to some repository, AFTER sending it to speech to text, in a different thread.  In this case you could save off not only the audio file, but the text translation as well.